# How to create "320x50" size ad in my pub center

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, ads

I created ad unit of size "480x80" for my app in dev.windows.com, now i have to create "320x50" size ad, when i created another ad in dev.windows.com for my app, it is creating again "480x80" size ad, please help me for this.

Comment: What thing you are creating? Are you creating an image? How you create image in  dev.windows.com?

Comment: @Sunteen yes..how to crated adunit id for 320x50 size ad's

Comment: What do you mean "it is creating again "480x80" size ad"? When you creating ad unit in Windows Dev Center, there is no ad size. See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipblE.png).

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT yes,,there no size when as unit created in dev center, but how can i create 320x50 size image ad for windows phone

Answer (score 0):

According to the notes in [**Test mode values**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/test-mode-values):

> **Important** The size of a live ad is defined by the **Width** and **Height** properties of the **AdControl**. For best results, make sure that the **Width** and **Height** properties in your code are one of the [supported ad sizes for banner ads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads). The **Width** and **Height** properties will not change based on the size of a live ad.

So for Banner ads, we can set the **Width** and **Height** properties of the **[AdControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.advertising.winrt.ui.adcontrol.aspx)** to specify ad sizes like:

```
<ads:AdControl Width="320"
               Height="50"
               AdRefreshed="OnAdRefreshed"
               AdUnitId="10865270"
               ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
               ErrorOccurred="OnErrorOccurred" />
```